# Make sure properties always occur together in type definition

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type, which has a property "path" and other properties which only can occur together. The following objects should be legal:

```
{ path: 'abc' }
{ path: 'def', valueTemplate: {}, valuePath: '' }
{ path: 'ghi', valueTemplate: {}, $valuePath: '' }
```

The following objects should not be legal, as a "valueTemplate" may only occur with a "($)valuePath":

```
{ path: 'abc', valueTemplate: {} }
{ path: 'def', valuePath: '' }
{ path: 'ghi', $valuePath: '' }
```

I thought this should express my conditions as type:

```
type DynamicInputTarget = { path: string } & (
  { valueTemplate?: never; valuePath?: never; $valuePath?: never }
  | { valueTemplate: object; valuePath: string }
  | { valueTemplate: object; $valuePath: string }
  )
```

At first it seems to work:

```
const t1: DynamicInputTarget = { path: 'abc' } // works fine
const t2: DynamicInputTarget = { path: 'abc', valuePath: '' } // fails, as expected
const t3: DynamicInputTarget = { path: 'abc', valuePath: '', valueTemplate: {} } // works fine
```

But when I try to handle t3, I get an unexpected compile time error:

```
const hasDollarValuePath = !!t3.$valuePath // unexspected error on accessing $valuePath
```

Error text:

> Property '$valuePath' does not exist on type '{ path: string; } & { valueTemplate: object; valuePath: string; }'. Did you mean 'valuePath'?

Why is that and how can I do this right??

[Link to TS-Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiiB2BDAtgSwGMBJTMAVxgBVsoBzYeAXjgG84xsYALALjgDOMKPkx04AXwCwAKDhwAZHAAUs%20ewBu2ADblgVYLjDauwAPz9MwDcCgBuOFt3AACl24W4Vm-bgASJz03Hk9vW0k1OAAfNkcdPQMjExhgfggAIwArYEIYB0DXd34hETEIuWjYgsTjUzSsnLz-AuC%20QWFRcWkKgEo7WVkAekG4Km58ATgAd2gAa0mAM1FU2UIITCEEAEY4FlZIzh5%20AHJsdMJj2W6hkbGJjigIABNyQmBJnlQn9-woYCe4LZHlBeKt1psYAAmfgYHAEEhkSg0eiMXZsA5FODHb4LY4AGki1UMtRS-FY3WuMmGo3GkxmUHmcCWVlBMjWG3gMAAzDCsHgiKQKNRaAxmOiKoc2sd8YT4vpiclUmwJASKi1MdKrgMqbdadM5otlqz8AtlNyAHTqng9WT7CrsgQQbTAc3aCB0M1cy1y1o2mSU6l3SZA6CCYCGSaiNZQP65Y2mi0BH3uP12%20QOp0ut0exNW7h%20iRAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the other prop also `never` in your possible values:

```
export type DynamicInputTarget = { path: string }
  & (
  { valueTemplate?: never; valuePath?: never; $valuePath?: never }
  | { valueTemplate: object; valuePath: string; $valuePath?: never } // here
  | { valueTemplate: object; $valuePath: string; valuePath?: never } // and here
  );
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiiB2BDAtgSwGMBJTMAVxgBVsoBzYeAXjgG84xsYALALjgDOMKPkx04AXwCwAKDhwAZHAAUs+ewBu2ADblgVYLjDauwAPz9MwDcCgBuOFt3AACl24W4Vm-bgASJz03Hk9vW0k1OAAfNkcdPQMjExhgfggAIwArYEIYB0DXd34hETEHAPjCkMtrcOk5aNiCxONTNKycvP8C4L5BYVE6fMre0NqoCIaASjtZWQB6ebgqbnwBOAB3aABrdYAzUVTZQghMIQQARjgWVkjOHn4Acmx0wkfZeoWllbWOKAgACbkQjAdY8VAA0H4KDAAFwWz-KC8Y6nc4wABM-AwOAIJDIlBo9EY1zYdyKcEekL2jwANJFmoZWil+Kx6p8ZItlqt1lsoLs4AcrMiZCczvAYABmLFYPBEUgUai0BjMUkNe59R60+mVFrJVJsCR0ho9cmaj5zDnfbmbHb7Q7C-B7ZSSgB0Jp4U1ktwaooEEG0wBd2ggdGdErdI3cnpk7MdYZdFWcvWj3vkvv9geDoddiaCUbgnJ4v1+oBQuVhglEIIQErgAIgoMwj3g3GwNjg2G6kZ4fwgKFgiA+QA)